# React component with list

Tags: reactjs

I have created a Card component which also involves a list inside, a bit of this code below:

Card.js

```
export const Card = ({ feature }) => {
*some code*

return (
*some code* 
<ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-6">
   <li className="flex">
      <CheckIcon className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-yellow-500" aria-hidden="true" />
      <span className="ml-3 text-gray-500">{feature}</span>
   </li>
</ul>

)
}
```

Now I use Card.js in another component ManyCards.js

```
const pricing = {
  tiers: [
   {
    features: [
        'Unlimited products',
        'Unlimited subscribers',
        'Advanced analytics',
        '1-hour, dedicated support response time',
        'Marketing automations',
        'Custom integrations',
    ],
   }
  ]
}

export default function ContractInfo() {
 return (
    <div className={formStep === 0 ? 'block' : 'hidden'}>
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-24 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mt space-y-12 lg:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">
          
          {pricing.tiers.map((tier) => (
            <Card
              feature={tier.features.map((feature) => ())}
            />
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
}
```

How do I get all features listed? I assume with map, but how exactly? I am super new to react. These are just bits of code, to demonstrate the issue, I am only stuck with the features.

Comment: {pricing.tiers.map((tier) => (
    <>{
        tier.features.map((feature) => <Card feature={feature} />)
    }</>
))}
?

Comment: renders the whole card with each feature as list item

Answer (score 0):

iterate array using `map` similar to  `pricing.tiers` just pass `tier.features`

```
export const Card = ({ feature }) => {
  return (
    <>
      return (
      <ul role="list" className="mt-6 space-y-6">
        <li className="flex">
          <CheckIcon
            className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 text-yellow-500"
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
          <span className="ml-3 text-gray-500">{feature}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      );
    </>
  );
};

export function ContractInfo() {
  return (
    <div className={formStep === 0 ? "block" : "hidden"}>
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-24 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="mt space-y-12 lg:space-y-0 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-x-8">
          {pricing.tiers.map((tier) => (
            <Card
              feature={pricing.tiers.map((tier) => (
                <>
                  {tier.features.map((feature) => (
                    <Card feature={feature} />
                  ))}
                </>
              ))}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```